# Background for Gross-Zagier paper

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, intersection-theory

I have been reading the paper "Heegner points and derivatives of $L$-series" by Gross and Zagier.

[Link to the paper.](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/BF01388809/fulltext.pdf)

In section III of the paper, they use intersection theory to express a local height at a non-archimedean place in terms of an intersection product. I have been having trouble understanding the algebraic geometry in this section.

So far I have been reading chapters 7 and 9 of Qing Liu's book "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves", but it seems as though I will need to learn scheme theory in more technical detail in order to get anything out of it.

I have read through the non-archimedean argument in Gross-Zagier's paper "On singular moduli", which can be regarded as a special case of the "Heegner points and derivatives of $L$-series". This has helped motivate the use of Hom-sets between points of $X_0(N)$, but doesn't seem to require the intersection theory arguments in the latter paper (maybe this is present in the form of Deuring's lifting theorem).

Finally I will state my question. Where should I look in order to get the necessary background to understand these calculations?

Comment: FWIW In 3.3 they refer to 0.1 which refers to [14] that cites [1] 
[Arakelov, S. J. Theory of intersections on an arithmetic surface](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=472815).

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks! I'm taking a look at the paper now